# Grails richui autocomplete for cloned textbox

Tags: jquery, grails, autocomplete, grails-plugin, gsp

I am using `grails richui autocomplete` field in my app.
It works fine for my static textbox but when I clone the textbox this feature is not working for the cloned textboxes and it shows no error even.

Any idea of how to fix this

Here is my code:

```
<resource:autoComplete skin="default" />
```

at top

```
<richui:autoComplete name="filterLocation1" id="filterLocation1" delimChar=";"  class="location_txtbox" action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'abc/yyy')}" style="margin-left:5px;"/>
```

This is my autocomplete field

and I am cloning like this

```
var counter = 1;
$("#addRow").click(function() {
counter++;
var cln = $('#static_table tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
cln.find("[id^='filterLocation']").each(function(i, val) {
    val.id = val.id.match(/^([^0-9]+)[0-9]*$/)[1] + "" + counter;
});

return false;
});
```

I clone the entire row, do some hide/show operations and increment the ids.

Comment: lots of idea about how to fix it... but you need to show us your code....

Comment: I have edited and gave my code bipen.....

Comment: how are you calling the autocomplete in jquery??

Comment: No I am calling autocomplete through jquery.The <richui:autoComplete> tag worked for the static row.And I dont know how to call in jquery.

Comment: Is there anything I have to do specifically to make autocomplete to work for that field

Comment: sorry my second comment is wrong it is.. No I am not calling autocomplete through jquery.The <richui:autoComplete> tag worked for the static row.And I dont know how to call that using  jquery

Comment: be aware that your <richui:autoComplete /> tag is executed serverside, you should take a look at the rendered/generated html/js to get an idea how to also clone the functionality or what could go wrong by cloning it (duplicate id´s i guess)

Answer (score 0):

When you clone the `tr` it clone all the content, it include the `javascript` create by the plugin. This cloned script uses the `id` of the `text field` to make it `auto complete`. This `id` and text field is required to change to make cloned autocomplete works.

I use following script to change that ids:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    function asd() {
        var cloneContent = "<tr>" + $("#firstTrToClone").html().replace(/giveAUniqueId/g, "giveAUniqueId" + counter++) + "</tr>";
        $("#tableId").append(cloneContent);
    }
</script>
```

**Following is my full working page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<resource:autoComplete skin="default"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    function asd() {
        var cloneContent = "<tr>" + $("#firstTrToClone").html().replace(/giveAUniqueId/g, "giveAUniqueId" + counter++) + "</tr>";
        $("#tableId").append(cloneContent);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<g:form>
<table id="tableId">
    <tr id="firstTrToClone">
        <td>
            <richui:autoComplete name="name" id="giveAUniqueId" action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'oauthCallBack/test')}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</g:form>

<button onclick="asd()">Clone</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Try it..,.