# Grails jQuery-ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, autocomplete

So I'm attempting a different route to using autocomplete within grails, here's what I've got so far...

"Object" Controller (yeah I know thats a really bad name now in hindsight): -

```
def objectFinderAJAX = {
    def objectsFound = Object.withCriteria{
        ilike 'objDesc', '%' + params.term + '%'
    }
    render (objectsFound as JSON)
}
```

In the head of the page I've got this: -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#eventList > tbody > tr").find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: '<g:createLink controller='Object' action='objectFinderAJAX'/>'
        });
    });  
});
```

And within the body I've got a table that looks, in its simplified form, like so (this is constructed with multiple AJAX calls on load) :-

```
<table id="eventList">
        <col width="500">
        <col width="750">
            <tr id = 0 class="even" name="main">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table id = "sub">
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Action</b></td>
                            <td><select style="width:375px;" name="events[0].id" required="required" id="events[0].id" ><option value="11" >Check a links displayed text</option></select></td>
                            <td>
                                <b>Object</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input style="width:500px" id="autoLook[0].id" name="autoLook[0].id" value= "Browser"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Bot nothing is happening when I type anythign in the input, any clues?  I even tried adding in a println to the controller just to output anything and its not registering that...  I cant see anything happening within firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going back to utilising richui which pretty much did everything I needed out of the box once I resolved the issue around changing IDs and names.

Original issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052417/grails-richui-autocomplete-passing-object-to-function-or-updating-object-id/20079200?noredirect=1#comment29987830_20079200).

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is the way `g:createlink` has been used.

It should be like this:

```
${createLink(controller: 'object' , action:'objectFinderAJAX')}
```

Just using the g:createLink will render it as a string. Also the controller convention dictates to use camelCase meaning should start with lowercase letter.

this [link](http://alidadasb.blogspot.com/2011/12/enabling-jquery-autocomplete-with.html) may also help you to get it work:

Comment: I've changed the javascript to now read as you've said but still no dice, I put a println into the controller but that never triggers either so I'm missing something fundamental...  Thanks for the link you've provided, its quite different to how I'm currently running things so will require a bit of a re-write, as adding in this autocomplete was a "nice to have" that I thought would be simple and I've got bigger fish to fry at the moment.  Thanks for the pointer I'll check it out later! :)